# How can one assign StoreFileListener implementations via ServiceWrapper?

Tags: chronicle-queue

As of Chronicle-Queue v4.5.27, it seems like the ServiceWrapperBuilder needs to be enhanced to include StoreFileListener assignment?  If there's a different construct, again, by way of *ServiceWrapper* queue creation, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

The ServiceWrapperBuilder is intended as an example.  Most likely you will want to build your own wrapper to suit your needs.

> If there's a different construct, again, by way of ServiceWrapper queue creation, what is it?

Its the one you write. For our projects we write one to suit the project.

Comment: Will do, Peter; thanks!  Perhaps indicating it's an example/starting point in the class's JavaDoc would reinforce that.  Thanks again.